# HttpClient How to set Connection Timeout in individual GetMethod

Tags: java, connection, timeout, httpclient

In my web application I have a global static HttpClient that is used in many parts of the application. It is created like this:

```
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
HttpConnectionManagerParams params = new HttpConnectionManagerParams();
params.setConnectionTimeout( 15000 );
params.setSoTimeout( 15000 );
connectionManager.setParams(params);
httpclient = new HttpClient(connectionManager);
HttpClientParams clientParams = new HttpClientParams();
clientParams.setParameter("http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects", true);
clientParams.setParameter("http.protocol.max-redirects", 4);
httpclient.setParams(clientParams);
```

The timeouts are fine for most use cased, but in a specific call I would like a shorter timeout. So I have:

```
GetMethod get = new GetMethod(finalUrl);

get.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(1000));
get.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout", new Integer(1000));
HttpClientUtil.getShortTimeoutInstance().executeMethod(get);
```

It does not work. The connection timeout is still 15000. Can I set a specific connection timeout in the GetMethod without creating a new HttpClient instance (this is because I believe creating a new HttpClient instance would not be a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at

> ./impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java

method

```
ClientConnectionRequest requestConnection(final HttpRoute route, 
                                          final Object state)
```

Once the connection pool has been initialized for the route, the originally configured value for socket timeOut will continue to be used unless you extend/override it.

```
public ClientConnectionRequest requestConnection(
        final HttpRoute route,
        final Object state) {

    final PoolEntryRequest poolRequest = pool.requestPoolEntry(
            route, state);

    return new ClientConnectionRequest() {

        public void abortRequest() {
            poolRequest.abortRequest();
        }

        public ManagedClientConnection getConnection(
                long timeout, TimeUnit tunit) throws InterruptedException,
                ConnectionPoolTimeoutException {
            if (route == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Route may not be null.");
            }

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("Get connection: " + route + ", timeout = " + timeout);
            }

            BasicPoolEntry entry = poolRequest.getPoolEntry(timeout, tunit);
            return new BasicPooledConnAdapter(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.this, entry);
        }

    };

}
```